# How to use switch case in onSelected/onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to use switch case in onSelected ? If-statement works fine

[image: error]

```
return GroupButton(
  spacing: 5,
  isRadio: true,
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  onSelected: (index, isSelected) => {

    if(true){

    }

    

    switch () {
      case :
        
        break;
      default:
    }

  },
```

i am quite sure that i am not missing a }

Comment: add your code snippet

Comment: try to remove =>

Comment: @JimChiu damn.. thx a lot - that did the job; can you explain why it´s working now ?

Comment: welcome bro !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, this can be useful for you. You need to remove => in your code.

```
    GroupButton(
          isRadio: false,
          spacing: 10,
          onSelected: (index, isSelected) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0:

                break;
              default:
            }
          },
          buttons: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"],
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just remove **=>** because when you use => do not declare your methods using inside curly braces **{ }**

you used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/group_button) widget

Answer (score 0):

pass somthing to Switch like isSelected variable or somthing you want to condition it